# datatype for math calculations like BMR function

Tags: c#, math

I'm writing a BMR function, should I be using a decimal type as my return value for highest percision? (C#)

Comment: That's an easy one, check this: 
http://www.acronymgeek.com/BMB  :D

Comment: Groo, you just lost the game. Do not pass go, do not collect $200.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you mean the [basal metabolic rate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metabolic_rate), I'd use double. We're talking about *natural* quantities here which don't have discrete values - we might say that something weighs 10.25kg for example, but that's already an estimate. It's not like currency, where $10.25 is *exactly* that amount of money.

I reckon a reasonable rule of thumb is "double for science, decimal for finance" - but it's not an absolute rule, obviously.